# Local lightroom catalog, photos on network share, but synchronize says 0 photos?

Tags: lightroom, windows, os-x, network

I am trying to set up the ability of my Windows machine to run Lightroom and access the photos that I have stored on my iMac.

I have the main lightroom catalog on the iMac, not shared, and I'm saving metadata information to sidecar files.

I have shared the main folder of my user on the iMac to the network, and I am able to connect to it from my Windows machine and both read, write, and delete files just fine through Windows explorer.

To clarify:

- I am **not** sharing the catalog in any way
- I want to share **only** the photo files (.CR2, .XMP, .JPG)

My photos are stored under ~/Pictures on the iMac.

I then fire up Lightroom on my Windows machine, and add a folder to `\\imac\lassevk\Pictures`, this seems fine.

But, 0 photos. Right-click and select Synchronize gives me this dialog:

[image: synchronize folder in lightroom]

Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

If it matters:

- OS X Mavericks
- Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Lightroom 5.3 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing [SMBUp](http://eduo.info/apps/smbup) and dropped the built-in SMB system that Apple has created, apparently it doesn't implement all the protocols and functions necessary, so file enumeration is a bit flaky.

With SMBUp, Lightroom on Windows is now importing images as expected.